# rearrange the list according to the selection of the order

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a default list which is showing in a tabular format. Now above the table, I have one sort option. Now without giving the form and button for that sort option how shall I change the record according to the chosen order by option from the drop down select box. 
  I am trying to do that by making use of jquery. But ultimately, gone in vain.My code is like:

```
<?php
$other_account_sql = "SELECT `admin_id`,`username`,`admin_name`,`role`,`status`,`email`,`contact_no`,`location`,`creation_date` FROM `admin_details` WHERE `username` <> '".$_SESSION['existingUser']."'"; //this is for getting default lists 
?>
```

---

```
<!-- html code-->
<select name="sort_selection" id="sort_selection" class="soring_select">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="admin_name" >Name</option>
    <option value="email" >Email Id</option>
    <option value="location">Location</option>
    <option value="contact_no">Contact No</option>
</select> 
<!--end of html code-->

<!-- js code-->
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#sort_selection').change(function(){
    var str = "";
     $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
     });
    }); 
    });
</script>
<!-- end of js code-->
```

now my issue is how shall I change the query according to the selection? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

here you go pal

```
<?php
$other_account_sql = "SELECT `admin_id`,`username`,`admin_name`,`role`,`status`,`email`,`contact_no`,`location`,`creation_date` FROM `admin_details` WHERE `username` <> '".$_SESSION['existingUser']."'" ORDER BY ". $_POST['sort_selection'].: ASC;
?>
```

good luck

Comment: But I am not supposed to click submit button...then how the $_POST['sort_selection'] will be getting?